Create Laravel model event listeners when you don't first retrieve the model
In Laravel, you can register model events such as:
class User extends Model
{
    protected static function booting(){
        static::creating(function (self $user) {
            $user->is_bald = rand(0,1);
        }
        static::deleting(function (self $user) {
            $user->roles()->delete();
        });
    }
}

So now I don't have to remember to handle common tasks during creating/updating/deleting/restoring... I can just
$user = User::create(['name' => 'Phil']);
$user->delete();

But what if I'm not returning initiated models before performing such events?
// this just makes a straight up Db call, one database roundtrip
User::whereIn('id',[...])->delete();

Is there a Laravel way of listening for Eloquent events that bypass generating a Model instance first? Now it feels like having registered a model event is just creating a false sense of security. I assume there MUST be a Laravel-flavored way I'm just missing.

No there is not. You are calling a delete function on a Eloquent Builder instance. Therefore the delete is executed directly on the database without retrieving the items. The parameter for each event is an instance of the related model. That means that the models must be retrieved for the events. For example in your deleting event you should loop trough all roles and delete them one by one to fire the events for those items.

Just not use observers - probably this is a worst thing in laravel.

@WillemvanDam that was my fear. How would one go about accomplishing the same goal? If one has 1000+ models that they're batch updating in the app, that of course would perform terribly making n+1 calls.

Obviously doing model event listeners is helpful for consistency, and also allows you to hand off things to other developers without needing to constantly remind them of the extra tasks. (We've all had those coworkers... the current codebase I've inherited is atrocious.)

@Maksim how so? Is it because of the false sense of security, or something else? I've been slowly adding them and advocating for their use to my team, along with Global Scopes and other forward-thinking features.

This is because observers add chaos in logic - many side effects just on saving/updating - you cannot predict what be done without read the whole code base.

@phil-tune There is no easy/good solution for this. You could create a static function that will do the updating for the related models of the User model. You then should call this in the events and also call this when using the Builder to update models. This function should do this based on the ids of the User models that are updated. Deleting of related models could be fixed by cascading on delete.

@WillemvanDam that actually doesn't sound terrible for very specific tasks. Though I'd only ever batch delete in a single controller method, so that particular logic would just go in there. (Which probably is best anyway because it'd be more efficient to make a single delete request for all children.) I'm just thinking, sadly, of other potential direct DB calls that will ignore my extra cleanup tasks. Thanks for the reply, I affeared this would be the case.

@phil-tune Yes, direct DB calls will ingore everything that you have done. There is only one way to fix this, but this is not the Laravel way. Just use a trigger in the database. As this is not available in the code base, this could be problematic when changing the table structure, so creating tests for this is recommended.

No, model events are not fired when the model has not been instantiated.  In the example you provided, you should simply use a foreign key with CASCADE to delete related records.

Hmm, yeah maybe I should provide a more specific example. I have something akin to Thread and Message. Messages can be scheduled, so when the Thread is soft deleted, it should only soft delete Messages that are scheduled but haven't yet been sent (they won't get picked up by the Job). So doing CASCADE on the database wouldn't be enough.
